# Tasks CT Validation rules

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016

We are using SharePoint designer to build task approval workflow with task content type.

I need to perform validation on the content type fields before submit the task

> ex: I need to make sure the start date is greater than due date in SharePoint content type

Is it possible?!

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I don't think it's possible as OOTB!**

---

**You have two options to achieve your goals!**

- Build your custom content type and attach it with your workflow! It would be easy to handle and manage all your business rules.

> Check [Programmatically Creating a SharePoint Content Type](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2011/04/29/programmatically-creating-a-sharepoint-content-type/)

- Use JS code to validate your rules in Script Editor web part, but in this case, you will get js errors! in case, the current content type doesn't contain the required field.

> Check [How to do validation on custom Form - Content Editor!](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226542/how-to-do-validation-on-custom-form-content-editor)

Comment: You are right, it's not possible without code